# Desktop Application Engine (2D)

Tags: library, cross-platform

I want to write an application for presentations and knowledge management. I've already found some useful libraries for the "multi platform native UI stuff" and things but what I can't seem to find is something like a "2D Desktop Application Engine".

I am talking about a library or an engine that will help me to create a desktop-like environment. What I mean by that is e.g. that I don't want to have to take care e.g. about clicking events, window-message passing and/or window ordering and basic stuff like that. But on the other hand it should not restrict me from anything design related.

At some point I was already thinking about using a 2D game engine for such a task but I am afraid that I'd have to implement the "desktop-like-behavior" part myself and this just does not feel right in the year of 2015.

So does anybody know a library that would fulfill my needs? Best regards and thank you for any help!

**Language requirements:** Compiled, not Java

Comment: Not exactly my area of expertise – but when asking for a library, I'd say it very much matters what programming language it should support. May I suggest you [edit] your question and include that?

Comment: @Izzy Good point. I have added the requirements though I guess they are heavily pointing to C/C++ :D

Comment: I bet you wouldn't like recommendations on Fortran, maybe not even Pascal ;) I was rather thinking you'd name the language(s) you want to have supported – not one you don't need. I better "shut up" now (as I said, not really my area of expertise), but it looks a bit broad to me this way. Don't you even have a favored set of languages? You "already found some useful libraries" for a part of your task. Don't you want the others matching them?